# Cannot rig an object anymore

Tags: modeling, rigging

I am fairly new to animating in Blender and so far this has been nothing but nightmare. I have never been so angry in months and this is just making my hair lose. If anyone is able to help with the problem, please tell me, I'm helpless.

I have been watching Youtube tutorials on how to rig a model and on my first try, It wen kinda good. I rigged the model, but It also highly demorfed other parts as well. I decided to try another rig, so I deleted the one I have and looked at another tutorial. Now, when I try to connect the armeture and the object, the option of parenting with automatic weights doesn't come up. I tried to look at like 5 tutorials on how to rig an object, but I still cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Is there some secret hidden inside Blender that I forgot about? Are there any websites explaining better on how to rig an object in Blender? Do I have to create the model again?

Thank you very much for your answers and I wish you nothing but the best day ever.

[image]

Comment: do you select both object and rig ?  also rig object should be last one to select you can tell if one of them has not a orange or red line round it

Comment: Your screen shot shows you to be in Pose mode.  Exit pose mode and then select your model by clicking.  Hold the shift key and select the armature.  With both selected, you should be able to parent the object.   For new animators, I suggest the tutorial series "Humane Rigging" as a starting point. It's old, but it's still very useful.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for help, I didn't realize that I have to select the model first, than the armeture, so I'm just an idiot. Anyways, thank you guys very much for your help!

Comment: "level pixel level" is very good and a little more advanced if you like rigging